# final form of answer for equivalence closure of a relation

Tags: set-theory, equivalence-relations

I struggling to understand the answer to this question.

Question:

> Let V = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} and let E = {(1, 7), (2, 1), (4, 1), (6, 5), (6, 6)} be a
> binary relation on V . Find the equivalence closure of this relation and state the
> equivalence classes.

I was able to figure out the answer (or what I thought was the answer), Which is party the answer

Answer:

> {(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (1, 2), (2, 1), (1, 4), (4, 1),
> (1, 7), (7, 1), (2, 4), (4, 2), (2, 7), (7, 2), (4, 7), (7, 4), (5, 6), (6, 5)}

But the final answer given is:

> The equivalence classes are {1, 2, 4, 7}, {3}, and {5, 6}.

How is this final answer achieved

Comment: Imagine if you will a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) made up of **v**ertices who are labeled $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ and **e**dges with an edge going from the vertex labeled $1$ to the vertex labeled $7$ and so on.  (*Note, the problem statement is very clearly hinting you should think of it this way given that they named the sets in your question $V$ and $E$*).  The equivalence close of a relation?  Consider thinking in terms of what the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) are in the graph.

Comment: You will find that $1,2,4,7$ are all in the same connected component of your original graph, that $3$ makes up its own connected component by itself, and that $5,6$ form their own connected component.  Add all necessary relations/edges missing such that each connected component is complete (including edges in both directions and loops)